# FFmpeg creating multicast with multiple streams from one source (live source)

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi :) I'm facing problems when creating multicast with multiple streams from one source (live source). The issue is that the encoding is slower than realtime. That is big issue for me as I'm processing live feed. The exact command and it's output you can find here:

**Command**

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -vsync 0 -deint 2 -drop_second_field 1 -surfaces 10 -i 'udp://@239.10.150.2:5004?fifo_size=100000000&bitrate=12000000'  -map i:0xc77 -r:v:0 25 -filter:v:0 fps=25,scale_npp=640:360:format=same:interp_algo=lanczos -aspect:v:0 16:9 -g:v:0 80 -vcodec:v:0 h264_nvenc -b:v:0 400K -minrate:v:0 400k -maxrate:v:0 400k  -map i:0xc77 -r:v:1 25 -filter:v:1 fps=25,scale_npp=720:405:format=same:interp_algo=lanczos -aspect:v:1 16:9 -g:v:1 80 -vcodec:v:1 h264_nvenc -b:v:1 1000K -minrate:v:1 1000k -maxrate:v:1 1000k  -map i:0xc77 -r:v:2 25 -filter:v:2 fps=25,scale_npp=1280:720:format=same:interp_algo=lanczos -aspect:v:2 16:9 -g:v:2 80 -vcodec:v:2 h264_nvenc -b:v:2 2500K -minrate:v:2 2500K -maxrate:v:2 2500K  -map i:0xc77 -r:v:3 25 -filter:v:3 fps=25,scale_npp=1920:1080:format=same:interp_algo=lanczos -aspect:v:3 16:9 -g:v:3 80 -vcodec:v:3 h264_nvenc -b:v:3 4500K -minrate:v:3 4500K -maxrate:v:3 4500K  -map i:0xc7a -ab:a:0 128k -ar:a:0 48k -acodec:a:0 aac -ac:a:0 2  -map i:0xc7b -ab:a:1 128k -ar:a:1 48k -acodec:a:1 aac -ac:a:1 2  -map i:0xc7c -ab:a:2 128k -ar:a:2 48k -acodec:a:2 aac -ac:a:2 2  -map i:0xc7d -ab:a:3 128k -ar:a:3 48k -acodec:a:3 aac -ac:a:3 2  -f mpegts "udp://@239.100.0.23:3234?overrun_nonfatal_option=1&pkt_size=1316
```

**And the output (speed should be 1> i hope)**

```
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:2 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:3 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
 Stream #0:1 -> #0:4 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
 Stream #0:2 -> #0:5 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
 Stream #0:3 -> #0:6 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
 Stream #0:4 -> #0:7 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://@239.100.0.23:3234?overrun_nonfatal_option=1&pkt_size=1316':=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A    
 Metadata:
   encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
   Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), cuda, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 400 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
   Side data:
     cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 400000/0/400000 buffer size: 800000 vbv_delay: -1
   Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), cuda, 720x405 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1000 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
   Side data:
     cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 1000000/0/1000000 buffer size: 2000000 vbv_delay: -1
   Stream #0:2: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), cuda, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2500 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
   Side data:
     cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 2500000/0/2500000 buffer size: 5000000 vbv_delay: -1
   Stream #0:3: Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main), cuda, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 4500 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_nvenc
   Side data:
     cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 4500000/0/4500000 buffer size: 9000000 vbv_delay: -1
   Stream #0:4(cze): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
   Stream #0:5(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
   Stream #0:6(hun): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
   Stream #0:7(ron): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
   Metadata:
     encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
frame= 2868 fps= 19 q=18.0 Lq=14.0 q=15.0 q=16.0 size=  134155kB time=00:01:55.88 bitrate=9484.0kbits/s speed=0.768x
```

Does anyone have experiences with something like this?

Comment: You can add `-preset:v` with value `fast` or `hp` for each video encoding.

Comment: Tried but without the result :/